# Update a raspberry pi to python 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x

Been attempting to update a 2 year old, untouched raspberry pi to be able to run a pip module that only runs on 3.6+. I updated the operating system and I've been attempting to update python following [this](https://itheo.tech/install-python-3-9-on-raspberry-pi) guide but I get to the last stage and it returns python 3.5.3. (note: i added the line to the bottom of the file because i couldn't find it)

I also tried
`sudo update-alternatives --config python` but it returned `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, try removing your current python version:

To know your version:

```
python --version
```

Then do this to remove Python:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove --purge pythonX.X
```

And finally, enable your repositories again, and install Python 3.9:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt install python3.9
```

Comment: i'm getting sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found

Comment: Try only to update, and then remove python.

Comment: cool, well something worked! just got a huge chunk of text saying the PostgreSQL version 9.5 is obsolete - do i need to do anything about that?

Comment: I think that you should update your PostgreSQL to avoid problems in the future. Please mark my question as correct if it helped you.

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa` causes:

aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Raspbian/buster